# How do I make a <div> move up and down when I'm scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I make a div element move up and down the page when the user is scrolling the page? (where that element is always visible)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You want to apply the fixed property to the position style of the element.

```
position: fixed;
```

What browser are you working with? Not all browsers support the fixed property. Read more about who supports it, who doesn't and some work around here

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/09/css-position-fixed-solution.html

Comment: @Jason, as much as I whole-heartedly agree with the sentiment, in the Corporate environment it may not be an option. Some companies can't/won't upgrade for a variety of reasons (like being held technologically hostage by a vendor... another story for another time). If s/he needs to support it then s/he needs to support it.

Comment: I wish I could download upvoted comments. Fire the vendor and move on, it will be well worth it. Or convince management to do so if not just for the vendor's failure to support the new browsers.

Comment: @Jason Couldn't agree more - screw IE6 and screw microsoft frankly for putting out such rubbish W3C non-compliant browsers to torture us with! Companies will adapt if all the websites don't support it.

Answer (score 68):

Just for a more animated and cute solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#div").stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
```

And a pen for those who want to see: http://codepen.io/think123/full/mAxlb, and fork: http://codepen.io/think123/pen/mAxlb

**Update:** and a non-animated jQuery solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#div").css({"margin-top": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", "margin-left":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"});
});
```

Comment: Very nice. I am using JQueryUI.resizable and it doesn't work with fixed elements so this is an excellent alternative, thanks.

Comment: @QF_Developer No worries at all.

Comment: @lk.annamalai no worries.

Comment: @think123 Any work around to do it with jquery but without animation.

Answer (score 14):

using `position:fixed` alone is just fine when you don't have a header or logo at the top of your page.  This solution will take into account the how far the window has scrolled, and moves the div when you scrolled past your header.  It will then lock it back into place when you get to the top again.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > Height_of_Header){
    //begin to scroll
    $("#div").css("position","fixed");
    $("#div").css("top",0);
}
else{
    //lock it back into place
    $("#div").css("position","relative");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var el = $('#Container');
        var originalelpos = el.offset().top; // take it where it originally is on the page

        //run on scroll
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var el = $('#Container'); // important! (local)
            var elpos = el.offset().top; // take current situation
            var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({ 'top': finaldestination }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `position: fixed;` in your div style.

I have checked and Its working fine in my code.

Comment: `position: fixed` isn't enough when you want your div to move only along with one of the scrolls, X or Y. The accepted answer is perfect. Just remove marginTop if you need only the horiz scroll. Remove marginLeft if you need only vertical.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out Remy Sharp's [recent article on fixed floating elements at jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/), which has a nice video and writeup on how to apply this effect in client script