# What is the HTML/CSS for a website header navigation that always stays at the top even when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a Div move up and down while Scrolling the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638895/how-do-i-make-a-div-move-up-and-down-while-scrolling-the-page)

I want to do a 100% width header navigation that stays anchored to the top of the site even when the user scrolls vertically. Kind of like this site:

http://www.hollencrest.com/

I would google it but I can't come up with the correct term.

So what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set the header's position to fixed:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left:0; right: 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M9RHn/

---

**P.S.** Remember to offset your page content from the top, so that the header does not cover any content before the user starts scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

add these properties in header classes

.header {position: fixed; top:0; z-index: 99; width: 100%;}

Comment: z-index is not necessary its just to make sure your header display on top of all layer.