# Panel sticked to the right of the page using html and css

Tags: html, css

There is something that I need to do using HTML and CSS, without javascript.

[image: Mockup]

I need help to define the css of "Outer Div". It has to go all the way to the bottom of the page. The height has to be 100% - 90px. The header has a fixed height. Inner Div's height has to be 60% of the height of Outer Div.

Can anyone help me? I can use html5 or css3 if needed.

Comment: Your mockup image is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to do this without JavaScript if all the dimensions are in %, but since 90px height is compulsory for the header, try these steps:

1) Give the **Header** a `z-index` value greater than the **Outer-Div**,
for example:

```
.header{z-index:10;}
.outer-div{z-index:0;}
```

2) Now, give the **Header** the following style:

```
.header{height:90px;min-height:90px;max-height:90px;}
```

3) And, the following style to the **Outer-Div**:

```
.outer-div{height:100%;}
```

4) Because you want the **Inner-Div** to be always visible, first you have to take it away from the **Header**, because **Header** has a higher `z-index` than **Outer-Div**, so:

```
.inner-div{margin-top:90px;}
```

5) Then give it a suitable height, I advise to use % inside of pixels for this **Inner-Div**:

```
.inner-div{height:50%;}
```

Comment: I'm also working on an alternate solution on jsfiddle, hope the answer got you in the right direction.

Comment: Here, take a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hdG9m/
So, I guess the trick I shared using `z-index` is the only possible solution (there may be others, I will surely explore them later)

Answer (score 1):

To make Outer Div's height 100%-90px, use:

```
#outerdiv {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

To make Inner Div's height 60%, use:

```
#innerdiv {
    height: 60%;
}
```

Both are in addition to your normal styles. Replace #outerdiv and #innerdiv with the IDs or classes of your outer and lower divs.

If you want to make the panel travel down the page as the user scrolls, use [this method on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638909/1979005). It is easy CSS. Just add `position: fixed` to Outer Div's CSS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesnt work. The margin-bottom does not reduce the actual height of my div. It continues some pixels after the bottom of the page

Comment: Then, use a javascript `window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("outerdiv").height = window.innerHeight()-90; }` with the CSS. If you have any top margins, add them to the subtracted value.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you sould catch the body resize event and in this event you have to calculate the height of Outer DIV. The following code sould be a good start for you:

```
function onBodyResize(e) {
    setProperty("OuterDIV", "height", (getDocHeight() - parseInt(getProperty("HeaderDIV","height"))) + "px");
}
function getDocHeight() {
    var r = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getClientRects();
    return r[0].height;
}
function setProperty(id,prop,value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.setProperty(prop,value,null);
}
function getProperty(id,prop) {
    var p;
    if (document.getElementById(id).currentStyle)
        p = document.getElementById(id).currentStyle[prop];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        p = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(id),null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid javascript

Comment: I think that you can't avoid javascript because the height of the document can only be calculated at runtime with javascript. The above code gives the exact heights that you are looking for.