# bootstrap - how to make a div always visible on scrolling

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a way to display a div, allays visible for a user. Scrolling.. that's my problem, see:

http://jsfiddle.net/makypl/966Uy/1/

This div should stay under div.left2 while scrolling down and get back to his original position while scrolling up.

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="l">
        <div class="left">
            <p class="trigger">Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1 Lorem...1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="left2">
            <p class="trigger">Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2 Lorem...2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="thisone">
            <p>This one should stay always visible
                <p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem... Lorem...</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

any suggestion welcome
thanks

Comment: Have a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/2/

Comment: Try this one : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638895/how-do-i-make-a-div-move-up-and-down-while-scrolling-the-page"

Hope it helped :)

Comment: probably use `affix` http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var top = $('.thisone').offset().top;
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $('.thisone').css('position','');  
    $('.left2').toggle('slow',function(){
        top = $('.thisone').offset().top;
    });

});



$(document).scroll(function(){
    //calculating the minimal top position of the div
    $('.thisone').css('position','');
    top = $('.thisone').offset().top;

    $('.thisone').css('position','absolute');                 
    $('.thisone').css('top',Math.max(top,$(document).scrollTop()));
 });
```

This should do the trick.
http://jsfiddle.net/966Uy/11/

**Edit:**
Made a few adjustment cause a bug could appear if the user scrolled during the animation.

Comment: it's works but in your solution @nubinub after scrolling up again, .left2 is hidden under .thisone

Comment: Are you sure ? It seems to work well here. Maybe you scrolled during animation, but i corrected this bug.

Comment: yep... works fine, only after scrolling dawn and up again, when triggering .left2, .thisone stays for a time of animation under .left2. thanks @nubinub

Comment: Maybe `slideToggle` instead of `toggle` would have  a better look on your browser.

Answer (score 11):

Use Bootstrap Affix, here is an example : http://bootply.com/62673