# Force div element to stay in same place, when page is scrolled

Tags: css, html

I created a `div` element, that I placed all the way on the right of my site. The only problem is that its at the top of the site, so if i scroll down it remains there.

How can I force it to remain in the same part of the page, when page is being scrolled?

This is, what I've managed to figure out myself so far:

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: #999; z-index: 10; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 83px;">
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a <div> move up and down when I'm scrolling the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638895/how-do-i-make-a-div-move-up-and-down-when-im-scrolling-the-page)

Comment: There's a new feature in CSS that bakes this functionality in automatically without javascript: `position: sticky`. 

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Just tried sticky, and it doesn't seem to be working yet in Chrome as of 2/11/2020.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed;`.

Example can be found [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HE5SF/2/).

Comment: The problem with the ```position: fixed``` is that it gets out of the flow, and things are going to overlap themselves.

Answer (score 11):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Answer (score 9):

You can do this replacing `position:absolute;` by `position:fixed;`.

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with your code.

`position : absolute` makes the element on top irrespective of other elements in the same page. But the position not relative to the scroll

This can be solved with `position : fixed` This property will make the element position fixed and still relative to the scroll.

Or

You can check it out [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lez1bukd/1/)

Comment: You answer is more or less the same than the previous ones .

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `position : absolute` and adjust the alignment using css parameters like below.

> ```
> .dvfixed{
>   position: absolute;
>   left: 100px;
>   right: 10px;
>   bottom: 5px;
>   top: 5px;
> }
> ```

OR

2. you can use float like below.

> ```
> .dvfloat{
>   float:right;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i my case the blue line I want it to stay fixed, i used sticky with right 0 and left 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dryEH.png)