# Need help - making an image a sticky

Tags: html, sticky

I would like to know how to make an image a "sticky" on my page so that when visitors scroll down the page, the image still appears on the side.

Comment: Look for something called position:fixed in CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make div stay in same place while scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746569/make-div-stay-in-same-place-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Romain Braun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873387/romain-braun) in the comment section, you will need to use CSS for that. In CSS there is a property with the name position whose value can be defined as fixed. It refers to the positioning of an object relative to the browser window, not relative to the document page. So, despite scrolling, the object to which this property was applied to will remain static.

Comment: You have answered 23 minutes ago, while 32 minutes ago this question was flagged as possible duplicate. Please, do not answer such qiestions here. They'll be eventually deleted.

Comment: No problem and no apologies needed! :> Everyone here was someday a beginner. Take it just as a simple note.