# Side div should scroll up and down but shouldn't collapse with bottom and header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

## Requirement:- side box(div on left side) should move up and down with scroll.

1. header have position fixed.
2. sidebox should move up and down with    scroll so I gave also
   position fixed.

The problem:-

Side box have position:-fixed so its collapsing with bottom. To avoid that I gave `bottom:350px;` So now, when I scroll down the side box is not collapsing with bottom but 
 it also moves up the side box from its original position when I am not scrolling.

To handle that problem I calculated the scroll height :-

```
let verticalOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

if(this.vericalOffset > 90){
    side box position: fixed;
    bottom :350px;
}
else {
    side box position: static;
}
```

Now again I faced one more problem

after `this.vericalOffset > 90{ bottom:350px;}` Header position is fixed also and now when I scroll down half of the side box is hidden by header.

I am stuck here.

Below is the  stack over flow question which was helpful for me 
[How do I make a <div> move up and down when I'm scrolling the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638895/how-do-i-make-a-div-move-up-and-down-when-im-scrolling-the-page)

## solutions I tried

`margin-top, margin-bottom, padding-top, padding-bottom` to elements of the side box, side box itself and also to the header.

I also tried to find the height of the side-box which was 600px - 1000px (because its dynamic) but couldn't find any relationship with vertical scroll

Please find sample [sample code pen](https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/vavBNv)codePen link

Comment: Please can you make a [mcve] of your current code that doesn't work

Comment: sample code pen link https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/vavBNv

Comment: putting your sidenav within the content div in a right column sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: Its not collapsing of content and side nav, its about collapsing side nav with footer. I am sorry I think I didn't make a good example

Comment: I can't change the height of side nav, also when i fully scroll down its collapsing with header

Comment: Its just an sample code of my problem, side nav is also dynamic in my problem, I tried to solve it by giving bottom but when I gave bottom it was collapsing with header. So it can;t be done because header and side nav both have position:fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Your question was not very well composed which makes it difficult to provide concise anwsers. The fiddle did help but you should have included the **relevant** code in your question.

That aside my understanding is that you desire the following functionality so I have have drafted an answer that should hopefully set you on your way.

---

Please view full screen and adjust view height to see the effects. The scroller is design to disable if the sidebar content is smaller than the viewing window.

```js
$(function() {
  scrollHdr();
  scroller();
});

function scroller() {
  if ($('.Scroller').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var side = $('.Scroller');
      if (($(side).height()) < (window.innerHeight)) {
        var top = $('.ScrollerWrap').offset().top,
          bottom = $('.ScrollerWrap').outerHeight() + top,
          maxY = bottom - $(side).outerHeight(),
          y = $(this).scrollTop() + 70; /*Extra padding for header menu*/
        if (y > top) { /*Scrolled past top of side bar*/
          if (y < maxY) { /*Scrolled past bottom of sidebar minus scroller height*/
            $(side).addClass('Active').removeAttr('style');
          } else {
            $(side).removeClass('Active').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: (maxY - top - 10) + 'px' /*manual padding*/
            });
          }
        } else {
          $(side).removeClass('Active');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

//Hide header on scroll down
var didScroll,
  lastScrollTop = 0,
  trigger = 0,
  navHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

//$('#Main').css('padding-top', navHeight);

// Shadow on Scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 0) {
    $('#Main').css('padding-top', navHeight);
    $('header').addClass('Active');
  } else {
    $('#Main').css('padding-top', 0);
    $('header').removeClass('Active');
  }
  didScroll = true;
});

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  // Ensure scroll more than trigger
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= trigger) {
    return;
  }
  // If past #Head add .NavUp.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('NavDown').addClass('NavUp');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('header').removeClass('NavUp').addClass('NavDown');
    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
}

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 0);

function scrollHdr() {
  // Activate class on scroll / Add shadow
  $('header').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('header').addClass('Active');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('Active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#Page{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 160;
}

header.Active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

header.NavUp {
  top: -70px;/*Match height of header*/
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #996;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.ContentWrap {
  display: flex;
  height:100%;
}


/*Left Side*/
.Content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background: #58c;
}

/*Right Side*/
.ScrollerWrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  margin-left: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.SidebarContent {
  width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.Scroller.Active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  /*Match script*/
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {
  /*Overwrite JavaScript*/
  .ContentWrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .ScrollerWrap {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
  }
  .Scroller {
    width: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    width:100% !important;
  }
  .SidebarContent{
    width:100% !important;  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Page">
<header>
  I am header my positon should be fixed and I am example from w3schools you can change my coding but my position should be fixed
</header>
<div class="ContentWrap">
  <div class="Content">
    On Scroll Sticky Header The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. I should move with scroll but should not collapse with footer Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur
    eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.
    Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset
    concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    On Scroll Sticky Header The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. 
    On Scroll Sticky Header The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. I should move with scroll but should not collapse with footer Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur
    eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo.
    Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset
    concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    On Scroll Sticky Header The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. 
    On Scroll Sticky Header The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et
    eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some
    text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert        
    his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
    laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
    gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
    et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. 
    
  </div>
  <div class="ScrollerWrap">
    <aside class="Scroller">
      <div class="SidebarContent">
        SIDE BAR Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo.
        SIDE BAR Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones
        no quo.
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  I am footer maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
</footer>
</div>
```